# Generalized linear systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, chow-groups

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety and let $Z\subset X$ be a subvariety. Let $[Z]$ be the class defined by $Z$ in the Chow group. Let $L(Z)$ be set of effective algebraic cycles on $X$ linearly equivalent to $[Z]$. When $Z$ is an effective divisor, this set is a linear system, and so has the structure of a projective space.

*Is there any reasonable geometric structure on $L(Z)$ in general?*

If so, has this problem been studied before? In particular, can one give estimates for the dimension of $L(Z)$?

Comment: I suspect you mean the set of effective cycles rationally equivalent to  $[Z]$ in the second sentence.

Comment: I know this is 5 years old, but the set you speak of at least appears in this paper for abelian varieties: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250126294